# What notation would you use to indicate element-wise exponentiation?

Tags: soft-question, notation

The context is I have a matrix of feature vectors $x = [x^{(1)}\ \ x^{(2)} \ \cdots \ \ x^{(n)}]^T$ but each $x$ is raised to the powers $0 \leq j \leq M$.

So it looks like this:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\left(x^T\right)^0 \\
\left(x^T\right)^1 \\
\vdots \\
\left(x^T\right)^M
\end{array} \right]
$$

But where the powers are element-wise. I guess maybe there is no other way of interpreting the powers.

Actually I think I just realized something, isn't this matrix just a Vandermonde matrix transposed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it appears to be a Vandermonde matrix. On Wikipedia they simply used the index notation

$$ V_{i,j} = \alpha_{i}^{j-1} $$